# Rundeck - Job call other job

Tags: rundeck

I need to know how to call a job from a other job. My objective is **Job A** call to **Job B** and send **a array param**.

Basically the **Job B** contains logical to start/stop services of the infrastructure and the **Job A** contains logical to get all services and the action to execute.

If it is not possible, do you know any alternative to be able to do it?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to do that. The first one is to create a parent job with the actions defined on an [option list](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/job-options.html#job-options) (which you can select with a textbox) and pass that actions to child jobs using arguments on [job reference steps](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/node-steps/builtin.html#job-reference-step).

Basically the child jobs evaluate that string and take some action depending on that. I did a working example (tested on Rundeck 3.3.3).

Parent Job:

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <context>
      <options preserveOrder='true'>
        <option delimiter=',' enforcedvalues='true' multivalued='true' name='services' values='stop_httpd,stop_ircd,stop_pop3,start_httpd,start_ircd,start_pop3' valuesListDelimiter=','>
          <label>Action to your services</label>
        </option>
      </options>
    </context>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>5c6e9603-6adf-4732-8b33-4e92068f1dcb</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>ParentJob</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <description>only for debug</description>
        <exec>echo "Services selected: ${option.services}"</exec>
        <plugins />
      </command>
      <command>
        <jobref name='HttpService' nodeStep='true'>
          <arg line='-action ${option.services}' />
          <uuid>58ca8e25-4473-4ba3-89be-29cfe6487b22</uuid>
        </jobref>
      </command>
      <command>
        <jobref group='services' name='IrcdService' nodeStep='true'>
          <arg line='-action ${option.services}' />
          <uuid>ea2b2e0f-f140-4716-a207-1690a42c2a59</uuid>
        </jobref>
      </command>
      <command>
        <jobref group='services' name='Pop3Service' nodeStep='true'>
          <arg line='-action ${option.services}' />
          <uuid>df9152d8-c4df-4698-b7c7-e8fdd622c59b</uuid>
        </jobref>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>5c6e9603-6adf-4732-8b33-4e92068f1dcb</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

Child Jobs (the services):

httpd:

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <context>
      <options preserveOrder='true'>
        <option name='action' />
      </options>
    </context>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <group>services</group>
    <id>58ca8e25-4473-4ba3-89be-29cfe6487b22</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>HttpService</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <fileExtension>.sh</fileExtension>
        <script><![CDATA[# current service
service=httpd

# check if the service is running
check_service () {
    # just a simulation, the service is up
    echo up
}

# up / down logic
if [[ @option.action@ == *"start_httpd"* ]]; then
    if [[ $(check_service) == "up" ]]; then
        echo "Nothing to do, the service is running."
    else
        echo "starting $service service..."
        echo "$service started succefully"
    fi
elif [[ @option.action@ == *"stop_httpd"* ]]; then
    if [[ $(check_service) == "down" ]]; then
        echo "Nothing to do, the service is down."
    else
        echo "stopping $service service..."
        echo "$service stopped succefully"
    fi
else
    echo "Parameter not recognized, use start or stop."
fi
]]></script>
        <scriptargs />
        <scriptinterpreter>/bin/bash</scriptinterpreter>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>58ca8e25-4473-4ba3-89be-29cfe6487b22</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

pop3:

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <context>
      <options preserveOrder='true'>
        <option name='action' />
      </options>
    </context>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <group>services</group>
    <id>df9152d8-c4df-4698-b7c7-e8fdd622c59b</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>Pop3Service</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <fileExtension>.sh</fileExtension>
        <script><![CDATA[# current service
service=pop3

# check if the service is running
check_service () {
    # just a simulation, the service is up
    echo up
}

# up / down logic
if [[ @option.action@ == *"start_pop3"* ]]; then
    if [[ $(check_service) == "up" ]]; then
        echo "Nothing to do, the service is running."
    else
        echo "starting $service service..."
        echo "$service started succefully"
    fi
elif [[ @option.action@ == *"stop_pop3"* ]]; then
    if [[ $(check_service) == "down" ]]; then
        echo "Nothing to do, the service is down."
    else
        echo "stopping $service service..."
        echo "$service stopped succefully"
    fi
else
    echo "Parameter not recognized, use start or stop."
fi
]]></script>
        <scriptargs />
        <scriptinterpreter>/bin/bash</scriptinterpreter>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>df9152d8-c4df-4698-b7c7-e8fdd622c59b</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

ircd:

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <context>
      <options preserveOrder='true'>
        <option name='action' />
      </options>
    </context>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <group>services</group>
    <id>ea2b2e0f-f140-4716-a207-1690a42c2a59</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>IrcdService</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <fileExtension>.sh</fileExtension>
        <script><![CDATA[# current service
service=ircd

# check if the service is running
check_service () {
    # just a simulation, the service is up
    echo up
}

# up / down logic
if [[ @option.action@ == *"start_ircd"* ]]; then
    if [[ $(check_service) == "up" ]]; then
        echo "Nothing to do, the service is running."
    else
        echo "starting $service service..."
        echo "$service started succefully"
    fi
elif [[ @option.action@ == *"stop_ircd"* ]]; then
    if [[ $(check_service) == "down" ]]; then
        echo "Nothing to do, the service is down."
    else
        echo "stopping $service service..."
        echo "$service stopped succefully"
    fi
else
    echo "Parameter not recognized, use start or stop."
fi
]]></script>
        <scriptargs />
        <scriptinterpreter>/bin/bash</scriptinterpreter>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>ea2b2e0f-f140-4716-a207-1690a42c2a59</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

Another way to do this is to use a similar action list with the names of the services and put a bash script iteration on the parent job, that script calls the services via [RDCLI](https://rundeck.github.io/rundeck-cli/). Example to stop services:

Parent Job:

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <context>
      <options preserveOrder='true'>
        <option delimiter=',' enforcedvalues='true' multivalued='true' name='services' values='httpd,ircd,pop3' valuesListDelimiter=','>
          <label>Services to Stop</label>
        </option>
      </options>
    </context>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>bb1206e8-f00c-4aa6-b7de-71c2fe8a43b1</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>StopServices</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <fileExtension>.sh</fileExtension>
        <script><![CDATA[#!/bin/sh

echo "Services to stop: @option.services@"

DataList=@option.services@

Field_Separator=$IFS

# set comma as internal field separator for the string list
IFS=,
for val in $DataList;
    do
        rd run -p @job.project@ -j $val -- -opt stop
        sleep 2
    done 

IFS=$Field_Separator]]></script>
        <scriptargs />
        <scriptinterpreter>/bin/sh</scriptinterpreter>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>bb1206e8-f00c-4aa6-b7de-71c2fe8a43b1</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

Child jobs (services):

httpd:

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <context>
      <options preserveOrder='true'>
        <option name='opt' />
      </options>
    </context>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description>Apache httpd Service.</description>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <group>services</group>
    <id>db05488e-0566-4ab9-b43e-e057a55f1198</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>httpd</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <fileExtension>.sh</fileExtension>
        <script><![CDATA[# current service
service=httpd

# check if the service is running
check_service () {
    # just a simulation, the service is up
    echo up
}

# up / down logic
if [ @option.opt@ == "start" ]; then
    if [ $(check_service) == "up" ]; then
        echo "Nothing to do, the service is running."
    else
        echo "starting $service service..."
        echo "$service started succefully"
    fi
elif [ @option.opt@ == "stop" ]; then
    if [ $(check_service) == "down" ]; then
        echo "Nothing to do, the service is down."
    else
        echo "stopping $service service..."
        echo "$service stopped succefully"
    fi
else
    echo "Parameter not recognized, use start or stop."
fi
]]></script>
        <scriptargs />
        <scriptinterpreter>/bin/bash</scriptinterpreter>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>db05488e-0566-4ab9-b43e-e057a55f1198</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

pop3:

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <context>
      <options preserveOrder='true'>
        <option name='opt' />
      </options>
    </context>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description>Dovecot pop3 Service.</description>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <group>services</group>
    <id>7285547c-99e1-4688-b180-a272327f590d</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>pop3</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <fileExtension>.sh</fileExtension>
        <script><![CDATA[# current service
service=pop3

# check if the service is running
check_service () {
    # just a simulation, the service is up
    echo up
}

# up / down logic
if [ @option.opt@ == "start" ]; then
    if [ $(check_service) == "up" ]; then
        echo "Nothing to do, the service is running."
    else
        echo "starting $service service..."
        echo "$service started succefully"
    fi
elif [ @option.opt@ == "stop" ]; then
    if [ $(check_service) == "down" ]; then
        echo "Nothing to do, the service is down."
    else
        echo "stopping $service service..."
        echo "$service stopped succefully"
    fi
else
    echo "Parameter not recognized, use start or stop."
fi
]]></script>
        <scriptargs />
        <scriptinterpreter>/bin/bash</scriptinterpreter>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>7285547c-99e1-4688-b180-a272327f590d</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

ircd:

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <context>
      <options preserveOrder='true'>
        <option name='opt' />
      </options>
    </context>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description>IRC Daemon Service</description>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <group>services</group>
    <id>a214976f-d8e8-4ce8-89af-d6b247b618e4</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>ircd</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <fileExtension>.sh</fileExtension>
        <script><![CDATA[# current service
service=ircd

# check if the service is running
check_service () {
    # just a simulation, the service is up
    echo up
}

# up / down logic
if [ @option.opt@ == "start" ]; then
    if [ $(check_service) == "up" ]; then
        echo "Nothing to do, the service is running."
    else
        echo "starting $service service..."
        echo "$service started succefully"
    fi
elif [ @option.opt@ == "stop" ]; then
    if [ $(check_service) == "down" ]; then
        echo "Nothing to do, the service is down."
    else
        echo "stopping $service service..."
        echo "$service stopped succefully"
    fi
else
    echo "Parameter not recognized, use start or stop."
fi
]]></script>
        <scriptargs />
        <scriptinterpreter>/bin/bash</scriptinterpreter>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>a214976f-d8e8-4ce8-89af-d6b247b618e4</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

As you see, this is scripting basically. The easiest way is to use a [ruleset strategy](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/workflow-strategies/ruleset.html), available on Rundeck Enterprise.